# How can I get all the data of one column in grails?

Tags: grails, grails-orm, hibernate-criteria

I'm new in grails and I'm trying to find the solution but I don't found any question here...

That I want to do is, I have this labels in my domain:

```
    String platform
    String appVersion
    String name
    String id
```

How can I get only all the data that I have store in appVersion column?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try the following code with your domain name

```
def c = DomainName.createCriteria()
def requiredList = c.list  { 
   projections {                    //projection does the trick
       property('appVersion')
   }
}
```

And if by chance you want to compare any value then:

```
def c = DomainName.createCriteria()
def requiredList = c.list { 
   eq('column_name', value_to_compare)
   projections {                    
       property('appVersion')
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Chetan, but I'm getting this error..... groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: createCriteria for class: com.test.NameConfig. Not sure because the name of the property is exactly the same that the String in the domain

Comment: It's working but I've changed c.get to c.list. Please change it in your answer, too!!